# How to set up an additional glibc compiler on centOS

Tags: centos, gnu, glibc

I'm using CentOS 7 and it is having glibc version 2.17.
I want to set up additional glibc compiler(same or another version) on this OS.
Please anyone help me in this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume you want to install **2.14** along **2.17** on centOS 7 and use it to compile your projects, just follow the steps below :

```
mkdir ~/glibc_install; cd ~/glibc_install 

wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.gz

tar zxvf glibc-2.14.tar.gz

cd glibc-2.14

mkdir build

cd build

../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14

make -j4

sudo make install

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib
```

PS: Building process takes 2.5 hours on slow AWS.

Comment: what is "~" meant for in creating the directory

Comment: "~" your home directory

Comment: Followed your steps. All done. Then how to verify that I'm having both the glibc versions.

Comment: Error messages are popping up on problem of sed-4.2.2-5.el7 package. Why is this??

Comment: The automatic bug reporting tool is reporting about those errors.          "A problem in the sed-4.2.2-5.el7 package has been detected."

Comment: This error message also displaying after following the steps. " Can't open configuration file /opt/glibc-2.14/etc/ld.so.conf: No such file or directory
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/glibc_install/glibc-2.14'

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib` will not work because the system dynamic linker is not compatible with glibc 2.14.

Comment: If export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib is not working, what can I do to continue my work. Could you please explain @FlorianWeimer